# Epson L1455 Series email server configuration for scanning

Tags: email, printer, scanning, email-server

I would like to set up a scan to email on my Epson L1455 Series.
Here is the email server configurations:

[image: email server configurations]

Here's the Wi-Fi configuration:
[image: wifi configuration]

Whenever I enter my email address and start to scan, it keeps showing that there is a connection error. Does anyone know why it can behave in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Two things that need changing:

1. If you are using Gmail, the SMTP server address should be smtp.gmail.com
2. Select either TLS or SSL as the authentication method. Then set the SMTP port number to either 587 (TLS) or 465 (SSL).

Comment: There is only SMTP and POP before SMTP AUTH. Which one I should select?

Comment: In that case, leave it at SMTP AUTH, but try the TLS & SSL port numbers.

Comment: thanks for answering I really appreciate it. When I put TLS & SSL port numbers following error has accrued: Unsupported communication method. Check the followings. -SMTP Server address -SMTP port number. Secure connection (SSL) is unsupported. Any suggestion?